# Populating Django form after AJAX request

Tags: javascript, ajax, django, django-templates, modal-dialog

I've got a django app in progress that is based loosely on the books example in the django book. There is a database of books which I have displayed in a table, when you click on the book it takes you to "/editbook/bookname" where it displays a ModelForm.

I'd like to move over to displaying the form in a modal dialog over the table - meaning the modal dialog code is already in place on the template like so (simplified!)

```
<div id="modal">
    {{form.as_table}}
</div>
```

The page loads and then an AJAX request is made to "/editbook/bookname" when the user selects a book; obviously the form won't display as the page is already rendered when the request is made - how can I update the  page suitably so the form actually renders once the request has been made?

Thanks

Comment: Not sure exactly what you're asking. Why can't you simply use Javascript to insert the form into the div?

Comment: struggling with how to request the form (instance included) using javascript. Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Most modal window implementations like jqModal, jQueryUI, Fancybox, etc, allow you to load content into the modal in an iFrame.

You could just create a view that contains your form that you load into the iFrame in the modal and go from there. It's a pattern I've used many times on several Django projects.

Comment: I'd still need to make a request to get the form based on an instance selected in the table though?

Comment: Sure. The parameter that you need to retrieve the instance you're editing is just part of the src attribute of the iFrame.